# How to call API with AntiForgeryToken using Postman in IdentityServer ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, postman, identityserver4

I'm trying to test my API with Identity Server Asp.net Core using Postman.

This is the way that I'm trying to do:

1. First request `HttpGet` to https://localhost:5000/Account/Login and in the response body I received:

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8MoS9upoM4dNp8Kx-AdvA-uYr13_PAkuMZpzYMV8UmxZq5GdLTvN-Ht5NpTLmPtlhL5d5z2Hu2vUJoJGhk1AMlARDcOwqgq7Cef1dfQL_vl4tIFM4kx9RZPz8DHU26-U9qLnKAIstZgR42-1FuGNh24" />
```

And in Cookie (not sure what it is though):
[image]

2. Then `HttpPost` to https://localhost:5000/Account/Login with `RequestVerificationToken` with the token received from the body `HttpGet` request.
   [image]

And always `error 400` as you can see in the screenshot above.

In Visual Studio, I can see that some request was caught but clearly was incorrect.
[image]

If I'll remove the attribute `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` then of course everything works fine but obviously, because that validation is disabled.

Comment: The input field name is `__RequestVerificationToken`.  Note the double underscore at the start.

Comment: Right, I was trying before with __ and the same problem occurs.

Comment: Are you including it in the body?  It's a form field, not a header.

Comment: Yes, I was trying body either.

Comment: What grant type are you using?

Comment: Both the antiforgery cookie and antiforgery form field are required so that antiforgery can function, which [can be verified in the DefaultAntiforgery implementation.](https://github.com/aspnet/Antiforgery/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery/Internal/DefaultAntiforgery.cs) I'm not certain why you would need to sign in to the IdP via Postman to test an API though.

Comment: He needs it to get a Bearer Token and to be able to add these Bearer tokens to his API requests, so that he can Test Methods that have the [Authorize] Attribute on them. I have the same problem.

Answer (score 6):

You'd need to do followings to send such a request:

1.) Enter __RequestVerificationToken key value (don't forget double underscores) into x-www-form-urlencoded

2.) You need to add .AspNetCore.Antiforgery cookie to the Cookies section in Postman.

For example like this
**.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.1XHiLFgQI2w=your cookie value; Path=/; Domain=localhost;Expires=Session;**

You can find .AspNetCore.Antiforgery cookie in Application section in Google Developer Tools

[.AspNetCore.Antiforgery cookie in Google Developer Tools picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXA4v.png)

[Add cookie in Postman picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKS1q.png)

Comment: This is great! Massive help @Burhan Savci! This should be ticked as the correct answer. Note that the .AspNetCore.Antiforgery might be different for you, depending on what you've named it. For me it was __AFC.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Andy. Yes, you are right, you can change the default name (.AspNetCore.Antiforgery) of the Antiforgery cookie. I used the default name in this example.

Answer (score 1):

Just spent a lot of time on this.

I did several things:

1. Setup an Environment and added a variable.
2. Added a pre-request script that...

   - Uses pm.SendRequest to Get the page
   - uses cheerio to find the first input field named __RequestVerificationToken and get its value
   - set the environmental variable to the value retrieved from the field
3. send the form data (since I'm using asp.net core, the values for the model), as x-www-form-urlencoded
4. and last, but not least, I added __RequestVerificationToken as one of the key value pairs in the form data and set it to the use the variable already setup

The main reason I am posting this answer is the last, I saw a lot of things on the web that indicated that name was supposed to be RequestVerificationToken, and that doesn't work, just leads to a 400 response (bad request).

Comment: Brilliant solution!

Comment: Definitely thought this might circumvent CSRF protection.

If implemented in a browser context (the thing we're trying to protect), this same technique does not work if the server also has CORS enabled.

Answer (score -2):

In postman, you’d need to set the content type to form url encoded.

And send the request Verification token in the header as "RequestVerificationToken"

However, if you just need a Bearer token then you need to call
 `POST https://<your identity server>/connect/token` with the
[image]